# Conemu: How to open directory in a current open tab?

Tags: task, conemu

I am trying to create Conemu task just to open some directory in the current console. This task setup, for example, opens this directory in a new powershell tab:

```
powershell.exe -new_console:d:C:\Users\User\example-dir\example-subdir
```

Is there a way to open it in a current console? I tried these, but it just opens new empty tab with text 'Press Enter or Esc to exit...':

```
powershell.exe -Command "cd example-dir"
```

I also tried:

```
powershell.exe -cur_console:d:C:\Users\User\example-dir\example-subdir
```

But it opens it in new tab, just like first one i posted.
Any help?

Comment: The only question is what for? The Task is intended to be a new console. With only exclusion that you may run one-command task in the prompt of the current console via "ConEmuC". What you want is not a running the new shell, but call CD in the existing shell. Why do you want to use task for such simple thing?

Comment: Well, it is a complicated long path. I don't want to type it manually each time.

Comment: Just define an alias. They were invented for such things.